# Hyperlink one word in a sentence in PowerPoint

Tags: vb.net, powerpoint

I'm currently inserting a sentence after the cursors position. When I insert the sentence I want to hyperlink one word in that sentence, however, for some reason the whole sentence is getting hyperlinked.

My sentence I'm inserting is "Please see {hyperlinkedText} for more information". I want the "{hyperlinkedText}" to be hyperlinked but not the whole sentence.

Please see code below.

The "titleName" is what I want to be hyperlinked and "fullText" is the senetence I'm inserting.

```
  Dim insertText As Tuple(Of String, String, Integer) = listCheckBoxSelectedItem.SelectedItem
    Dim titleName As PowerPoint.TextRange = PowePointApplication.ActiveWindow.Selection.TextRange
    titleName.Text = insertText.Item1
    Dim fulltext = $"Please see {titleName.Text} for more information."
    Dim selectedIndex = PowePointApplication.ActiveWindow.Selection.TextRange.InsertAfter("D")
    selectedIndex.Text = fulltext
    With titleName.ActionSettings(PowerPoint.PpMouseActivation.ppMouseClick)
        .Action = PowerPoint.PpActionType.ppActionHyperlink
        .Hyperlink.SubAddress = insertText.Item3
    End With
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see, in the code provided, `titleName` is the entire text selection, and that is why the entire text gets the hyperlink. It probably needs a sub-textrange for the piece you want to put a hyperlink on.

I've not tried this on VB, but from VBA, I believe you can use `Find` method of `TextRange` to get a new sub-`TextRange` just for that part, which you can then update the hyperlink settings. The code below just sets the hyperlink for the text `{hyperlinkedText}` part, if it is a substring of the selected text.

```
With ActiveWindow.Selection.TextRange.Find("{hyperlinkedText}").ActionSettings(PowerPoint.PpMouseActivation.ppMouseClick)
    .Action = PowerPoint.PpActionType.ppActionHyperlink
    .Hyperlink.SubAddress = "http://www.bing.com"
End With
```